# MySQL randomly assigns second port / PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My MySQL randomly assigns a second port to the requested address like this:

[2002] Cannot assign requested address (trying to connect via tcp://127.0.0.1:3306:3306)

This behavior is triggered on my localhost and on my servers as well, so I figured it might be my code. I'm connecting via a self-written class, which is using constants only to connect (which are correct, no second ports assigned within these constants), so I'm pretty clueless why this behavior is triggered sometimes and where the second port comes from. The execution of the script terminates when this error occurs.

I added the class to this post, if someone wants to browse through.

Any advise is welcome to fix or circumnavigate this.

Thanks in advance!

```
    class mysql{

        protected $query                = false;
        protected $lastquery            = false;        
        protected $result               = false;
        protected $row                  = false;
        protected $args                 = array('');
        protected static $mysqli        = null;

        public function __construct(\mysqli $mysqli = null){
            self::$mysqli = $mysqli;
            $this->establishAutoConnection();
        }

        // Tries to establish connection, if none is set.
        protected function establishAutoConnection(){
            IF(empty(self::$mysqli)):
                SWITCH($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']):
                    case 'localhost':
                        self::$mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWD, MYSQL_DATABASE);
                        break;
                    case 'AN IP.IP.IP':
                        $this->connectToSlave();
                        break;
                    default:
                        self::$mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST_SERVER, MYSQL_USER_SERVER, MYSQL_PASSWD_SERVER, MYSQL_DATABASE_SERVER);
                ENDSWITCH;
            ENDIF;
        }

        public function connectToSlave(){
            self::$mysqli = new mysqli(SLAVE_HOST_SERVER, SLAVE_USER_SERVER, SLAVE_PASSWD_SERVER, SLAVE_DATABASE_SERVER);
        }

        public function connectToMaster(){
            self::$mysqli = new mysqli(MASTER_HOST_SERVER, MASTER_USER_SERVER, MASTER_PASSWD_SERVER, MASTER_DATABASE_SERVER);
        }

        // Sets the PDO arguments, which need to be replaced by '?'
        public function setArgs(&$data, $type = false){
            $type = $type ?: $this->getTypeString($data);
            $this->args[0] .= $type;
            $this->args[] = &$data;
            return $this; 
        }

        // Reset function needs to be called in order to make a new query.
        public function reset(){
            $this->args     = array('');
            $this->row      = false;
            $this->result = false;
            return $this;
        }

        // Loops through the found results.
        public function loopThroughResults(){
            return ($this->row = $this->result->fetch_assoc())
                ? true
                : false;
        }

        // Returns the row unformatted. If no result is found an emtpy array is returned.
        public function getRow(){
            $this->row = $this->row ?: $this->result->fetch_assoc();
            return $this->row ?: array();
        }

        // Returns the first result of the first row.
        public function getSingleResult(){
            FOREACH($this->getRow() as $assoc => $value):
                return $value ?: false;
            ENDFOREACH;
            return false;
        }

        // Returns the result by rowname
        public function getByName($name){
            return isset($this->row[$name]) 
                ? $this->row[$name]
                : false;
        }

        // If a new query is made, while the former query has not been resetted, a warning is stored or an error is thrown.
        protected function isResetted(){
            IF($this->result):
                $this->warning("PDO has not been resetted from query: ". $this->lastquery ." // new query: ". $this->query);
            ENDIF;
        }

        // Executes the prepared query.
        public function query($sql){
            $this->query = $sql;
            $this->isResetted();
            $this->lastquery = $sql;
            IF($prep = self::$mysqli->prepare($this->query)):
                IF(count($this->args) > 1):
                    call_user_func_array(array($prep, 'bind_param'), $this->args);
                ENDIF;
                $prep->execute();
                $this->result = $prep->get_result();
                $prep->close();
            ELSE:
                $this->error("Query $sql failed to prepare.");
            ENDIF;
        }

        // Automatically generates the string of types for the submitted params if not set. ("ssisdss") etc.
        protected function getTypeString($string){
            SWITCH(gettype($string)):
                case 'string':
                    return 's';
                case 'double':
                    return 'd';
                case 'boolean':
                case 'integer':
                    return 'i';
                case 'array':
                    $this->error('Unserialized array submitted to PDO.');
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->error('Unknown param type submitted to PDO. ' . print_r($string) . ' type: ' . gettype($string));
                    break;
            ENDSWITCH;
        }

        protected function error($msg){
            IF(!new error($msg)):
                trigger_error($msg);
            ENDIF;
        }

        protected function warning($msg){
            IF(!new warning($msg)):
                trigger_error($msg);
            ENDIF;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you added the port number in your definition? So e.g.

```
MYSQL_HOST = 127.0.0.1:3306
MYSQL_HOST_SERVER = 127.0.0.1:3306
```

`mysqli` will use his default port settings on your server definition. So if you add the port number here, the result will be the same as your request error:

```
MYSQL_HOST = 127.0.0.1:3306:3306
MYSQL_HOST_SERVER = 127.0.0.1:3306:3306
```